# How can I tell if xscreensaver has my screen locked?

Tags: scripting, screensaver

I'm thinking through alerting stuff, and decided that, if my screen is locked, I'm not there so I should push the alerts to my phone. But, I cannot currently tell if the screen is locked. I could put something together with Perl and xscreensaver-command -watch, but I'd rather not have to make sure I have that process always running and all. That seems too heavy.

Is there something I'm missing? This seems fairly obvious.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See:

```
$ xscreensaver-command -time
XScreenSaver 5.15: screen locked since Wed Sep 26 16:26:15 2012
```

Comment: It seems that if I kill xscreensaver and then restart it from the command line, -time still reports "screen locked since" even if the screen is not locked.